# Reg Ex Testing Number Range Using \b

Tags: javascript, regex

I created a regular expression to test if an input is within the range 1-99. It tests correctly, but when I input 10, it shows there is an issue. I am guessing since the range [1-9] does not include '0'. How do I change the syntax to include "0" so that 10 is not rejected as an input between 1-99?

`var regex = /^(\b[1-9]{1,2}\b)$/;`

Answer (score 1):

try this pattern

```
/^\b([1-9][0-9]?)\b$/
```

Edit: adjusted capturing group

Comment: When we have anchors why do we need `\b`.They are not of any use here